# Is there any hack to override a class name with custom one?

Tags: ruby, oop

Let's say I have a class `Set` I want something like this for example

```
class Set
  def initialize(new_name)
    self.class = new_name
  end
end
```

If you do something like that `x = Set.new("Dog")`, `x.class` will return `Dog` instead of `Set`. The class above is not working as well!

Comment: Could you clarify the question? It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: for any class you create in Ruby when you try `Class.class` it returns `Class` right? I want to override the class with custom one! `c = Cat.new("liza")` `c.class` returns `Cat`

Comment: Is getting a different name from `#class` method all you need or you expect smth else from overriding class like that? Do you expect your object to become an instance of a different class after that assignment? Btw, may be it's none of my business, but why?

Comment: Actually I'm working on some experiments work Ruby, and I want to create objects on fly with just defining one class. ie `p = Obj.new("Post", fields..)` I want `p.class` to return `Post` instead of `Obj`.

Comment: @amrnt, if you want dynamically generate classes with fixed set of fields and no other logic you might find [`Struct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) class useful. Otherwise, you can dynamically generate class completely on your own and then create an instance of it. But I doubt there's a way to change class of already created object.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out! this should work ;)

```
class Obj
  def initialize(name)
    @klass = Object.const_set(name.capitalize, Class.new()).new()
  end
end
```

Give it a try:

```
dog = Obj.new("dog")
dog.class #=> Dog
dog.class.name #=> "Dog"
```